gcloud cli command create eventarc errors
I tried to create eventarc trigger with gcloud cli, in order to specify path patterns. Following the documentation. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/eventarc/triggers/create#--destination-run-service
https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/path-patterns#valid_patterns
and some online steps https://atamel.dev/posts/2022/03-02_path_patterns_eventarc/
However i received error as below:
ERROR: (gcloud.eventarc.triggers.create) Error parsing [trigger].
The [trigger] resource is not properly specified.
Failed to find attribute [location]. The attribute can be set in the following ways: 
- provide the argument `trigger` on the command line with a fully specified name
- provide the argument `--location` on the command line
- set the property `eventarc/location`

My command as below:
gcloud eventarc triggers create bq-trigger-test --destination-run-service=bigquery-upload \
--destination-run-region=asia-southeast1 --event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--event-filters="bucket=bucket-name" \
--event-filters-path-pattern="bucket=/projects/_/buckets/bucket-name/objects/**/filename.json"

I saw this issue but it should have been resolved:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/5057
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/pull/5348
Anyone facing the same? Or able to identify any issue from my command above?
thanks

I figured out why.
I have indicated the right name for the trigger in fact, but i need to provide --location. I mistakenly thought that I have provided the region but it was indicating the cloud run service ones instead. i need to tell eventarc the location of the triggers to create in.
Also a few other errors from my command - event-filters-path-pattern does not support all types.

For example, it wont work with
type=google.storage.object.finalize and bucket=/projects/_/buckets/bucket-name/objects/**/filename.json
also i had duplicated event-filters for 'bucket=xxx'
need to use audit logs instead.

So my final form of command that work is:
gcloud eventarc triggers create bq-trigger-test --location=asia-southeast1 \
--destination-run-service=bigquery-upload --destination-run-region=asia-southeast1 \
--event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" \
--event-filters="serviceName=storage.googleapis.com" \
--event-filters="methodName=storage.objects.create" \
--event-filters-path-pattern="resourceName=/projects/_/buckets/bucket-name/objects/**/file-name.json" \
--service-account=abcde.iam.gserviceaccount.com


The error is cryptic but accurate.
You're providing a shortname (not fully-qualified per the documentation) to gcloud eventarc triggers create
As a result the command needs to know both the Project and location. The Project is likely set in gcloud config get project but the location is not and the command fails.
As recommended,
Either: provide the fully-qualified name
Or: provide --location
